# display alert box in frontend to show errors of backend

Tags: oracle, jsp, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [show table deleted message in webpage when it is deleted from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646533/show-table-deleted-message-in-webpage-when-it-is-deleted-from-database)

I have used ORACLE 10g as database and JSP as my front end.

When users presses tabs data is fetched from the server and displayed
at the front end. 
I want to show an **ALERT box** in the front end when table is deleted 
in the back end or the connection to server is broken when a user
presses the tab.

How can I do it? ALERT box should display:

1. connection error to server when there is error in connection to 
   server
2. table is deleted when table is deleted in the backend while data 
   is being fetched from the front end by pressing the tab.

I've a jsp page where I've the frontend user interface as well as java code to fetch data from the server. it does not point to any other page.
I've googled and found some examples.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    //do something on success
  }
});
```

what do I do with the url option??

Comment: via `asynchronous` - XHR or jQuery request

Comment: @AVD plz can U provide me the links having examples.

Comment: Are you familiar with `JavaScript` and `jQuery` library?

Comment: That you have solved it - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I have sql statements in jsp page. like mypage.jsp contains sql queries, it fetches data from server directly, this page do not call to another page. what to write in url??

Comment: You say Onclick of tabs data is fetched from the server, so data is fetched through ajax? or the whole page is refreshed? One thing I will tell that you would have to use a Servlet which will process your database request and return an error response to show an alert. By the way this seems to be a duplicate of your other question as @HardikMishra mentioned.