# show table deleted message in webpage when it is deleted from database

Tags: jsp, jquery

I've to show errors in backend database or server in frontend.
(like table deletion,mismatch password,server connection etc.)
I am not getting idea to do this.

I've done:
**mypage.jsp**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
});
      </script>

<body>
<form id="test">
            <table id="data" cellpadding="5px;" cellspacing="5px;">
                <tr>
                    <td>name</td>
                    <td>c_price</td>

                </tr>

 <%
            Connection connection = null;

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
                try{
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@...","u_name","pwd");
                Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();

                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test_tbl");

            while(rs.next())
                {
                   %>

   <tr>
        <td><%out.print(rs.getString("name"));%></td>
        <td><%out.print(rs.getString("c_price"));%></td>        
   </tr>
    <% }%>

<%
            connection.close();
       }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error = " + e.getMessage());
     }//end of catch
    %>    

</table>     
</body>
```

while executing from front end, I delete the table test_tbl from the back end, but the webpage is not showing any alert. I also typed the wrong pwd but also 
it did not show any error. how can I solve this problem??

I've to show **alert boxes** when:

**when there is no table in the backend**.
the above ajax code shows alert boxes for n/w errors but **how to show alert box when there is no table in database or mismatch password/username**???

Comment: I hope you already know that it is a bad-practice to have database code in your JSP and also you can't have `<tr>`s inside `<td>`.

Please also work on a little formatting for your code. Thanks

Comment: @PrakashK ya I know that and tag error was just typo error. any way thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code for username/password checking through ajax and neither in the JSP, so can't give an answer for that.

Now for showing alert when there is no table, have you refreshed the page after you deleted the database table from backend (because I don't see an ajax call that fires of to check for the table other than the `catch` block)?

Also I don't think this: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error = " + e.getMessage());` would work in a JSP, instead you can try the following to show the message:

```
// your code ...
<%
        connection.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
%>
<div id="errorMsg" class="errorMsg">
Error = <%= e.getMessage() %>
</div>
<%
    }//end of catch
%>
// your code continues ...
```

You can also put some `javascript` code which picks up the `<div>` contents and shows an alert after the page has loaded completely.

If you can paste some code that shows the flow and also some more elaboration as to what you are doing, it would be helpful.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I deleted the table from back end simultaneously when I executed the front end. no case for refreshing the page...

Comment: first you must have deleted the tables and then you would load the page, right? I don't understand how (or why ;-)) you are doing it simultaneous?